# How to use recursion to print even positive numbers between a start and end

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

I am using python 3.0. 
The aim is to use recursion to print even numbers between a start and end limit.

For ex: if I type start as 0 and end as 10, then I expect an output 0,2,4,6,8,10, i.e. the even positive numbers between 0 and 10

Below is my code. I am trying to check s//2==0 whether each number is even or odd and if even i.e. s//2==0 then I am holding it in an array and using recursion to recall the function.

I am getting an error for s//2 as "maximum recursion depth exceeded". 
Please clarify where I am making a mistake

```
even=[]
def evenp(s,e):
    if s//2==0:
        even=[s]
        s=s+1
        evenp(s,e)
    else:
        s=s+1
        even=[s]
        evenp(s,e)
    return even

def main():
    str=int(input("\nEnter a positive number for start "))
    end=int(input("\nEnter a positive number for end "))
    if end==0:
        print("\nEnter ending value > 0")
        main()
    elif str<0 or end<0:
        print("\nStart and End values should be positive > 0")
        main()
    elif str>end:
        print("\nStart should be positive but < ending value ")
        main()
    else:
        print(evenp(str,end))

main()
```

Comment: The `even` you created at the beginning is not even used. `evenp()` creates a new local variable of the same name. And you are not even appending it. Doing `even=[s]` will just overwrite the list.

Comment: Where is your base case? How will your function end recursing?

Comment: This is a spectacularly *bad* use case for recursion, by the way.

Comment: @paxdiablo Indeed but let’s leave some doubts about the completeness of the snippet. Maybe there is more stuff we do not see. I hope ;) Otherwise a simple list comprehension would do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for a start, `s // 2` in *no* way decides whether a number is even or odd<sup>(a)</sup>, it simply divides it by two with integer truncation. You should be using the modulo function to decide odd or even:

```
if s % 2 == 0: itIsEven()
```

With that in mind, here's *one* way to do it. You'll notice I don't worry about putting them in a list since the requirements are simply to print them:

```
def printeven(num, lim):
    # Ensure we start at the first even number desired.

    if num % 2 == 1:
        printeven(num + 1, lim)
        return

    # If current number is within limits, print and recurse to next.

    if num <= lim:
        print(num)
        printeven(num + 2, lim)

printeven(1, 10)
```

This will output, as desired:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

However, I should mention that recursion in this case is not really suitable. It's best for situations where the "solution space" reduces drastically for each recursion level (such as *halving* in each level for a binary search).

If a recursive call cannot be optimised with tail call optimisation, it may quickly exhaust your stack space. For example, changing that `10` in the call to `1000000` does *exactly* that.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Unless you do something like:

```
if (s // 2) * 2 == s
```

but this is rather unnecessary when you have a modulo operator.

Answer (score 2):

In you function, you are calling itself in all cases. This causes the recursion. Issue is that you do not check for a stopping criterion (your `e`). So just add a condition in the loop that would return from the function without re-calling the function again. So at the end something like this:

```
if s == e:
    return
```

Also, `even` is overwritten when you do `even = [s]`. What you want is to append to the list: `even.append(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if s//2==0:
    ....
    evenp(s,e)
else:
    ....
    evenp(s,e)
```

the problem is that you never end the recursion.  typically there is a check,  e.g. for factorial(n). we return n*factorial(n-1). however we also have a check whether n==0 and just return with a value of 1 (terminating the recursion)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `%` to check if a number is even or odd, not `//`.

Another approach is to split your problem into two functions. Below their is one main calling function `positive_even()`, and one function that adds numbers to an accumulated list, `rec_positive()`:

```
def positive_even(start, end):
    if start < 0 or end < 0:
        raise ValueError("Must be positive numbers")

    # if start is even, add it to the accumulated list
    if start % 2 == 0:
        return rec_positve(start, end, [start])

    # otherwise, dont add start to accumulated list, because its odd
    return rec_positve(start, end, [])

def rec_positve(start, end, acc):
    # base case
    if start == end:
        return acc

    # copy start variable
    temp = start

    # If start is even, increment it by 2 for next number
    if temp % 2 == 0:
        temp += 2

    # otherwise, the next number with be even
    else:
        temp += 1

    # add to the resulting list
    acc += [temp]

    # recurse again, until base case is reached
    return rec_positve(temp, end, acc)
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> print(positive_even(0, 10))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> print(positive_even(1, 10))
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> print(positive_even(5, 10))
[6, 8, 10]
>>> print(positive_even(10, 10))
[10]
```

**Note:** I inserted the numbers in a list instead, can be easily printed out from here.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand you need to take all even numbers in range using some recursive function. I am not sure, but why you use "//" operator if you should use "%"? Also you should check limits, and in addition you can increase each even number by 2, and use independent array.

```
def evenp(buf, cur, end):
    if cur > end:
        return
    if cur % 2 == 0:
        buf.append(cur)
        cur += 2
    else:
        cur += 1
    evenp(buf, cur, end)

buf = []
cur = -9
end = 9
evenp(buf, cur, end);
print(buf)
```